# How do I find the number of lower case letters in Scheme Racket?

Tags: scheme, racket, uppercase, lowercase

I'm trying to find the number of lower/upper case letters in a string, but there is a problem with my code:

```
(define case
  (lambda (list)
    (if(char-lower-case? (car list))
       (case (cdr list))
       (+ 1 (case (cdr list)))
       )
    ))

(case (string->list "ScheMe"))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please specify what exactly the problem is with your code.

Comment: if first letter in the string is lower case, program do not return the (case (cdr list)). I do not check all string.

Comment: I solved, The solution is:                                                                                                        (define case
  (lambda (list)
    (if(null? list)
       0
    (if(char-upper-case? (car list))
       (case (cdr list))
       (+ 1 (case (cdr list)))
       )
    )))

(case (string->list "SeheMe"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your function you have two problems:

1. `case` is a predefined operator in racket/scheme
2. You don't test for an empty list.

Moreover, you use the parameter `list`, which is a primitive operator and should not be used as variable name.

Here is a working function:

```
(define (case1 lst)
    (cond ((null? lst) 0)
          ((char-lower-case? (car lst)) (case1 (cdr lst)))
          (else (+ 1 (case1 (cdr lst))))))

(case1 (string->list "ScheMe"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code lacks a base case. `(case '())` should evaluate to `0` but you get an error since you are doing `car` and `cdr` on `nil`.

**Other things that might be wrong:**

Your title indicates that you want to count lowercase letters but you increase for every uppercase.

`list` and `case` are names from the standard library. For R5RS it means undefined behaviour and for R6RS and later it means the library bindings would be unavailable. In `#!racket` (I guess you use this language since you tagged racket) it works as R6RS.